# Execute a stored procedure in a SELECT or FROM statement or a SQL function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures

Are there any possibilities to execute a stored procedure in a `SELECT` or `FROM` statement or a SQL function?

Like

```
select sp_name_and_parameters
from table_name_or_sp_name_and_parameters
```

or

```
select function_name(sp_name_and_parameters)
```

I have no ideas

Comment: Stored Procedures are not for this purpose. Thing you are looking for is Table valued Function.

Comment: Google "SELECT from stored Procedure", and reach this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

I would look at these two additional posts at stackoverflow:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506871/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-inside-a-select-query 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure 
 
  As aasim.abdullah has said, I would look into Table valued functions more too.  Information about them can be found here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx  
  
I know the Microsoft link refers to SQL Server 2008 R2, the theory is the same though.